# Mongoose or query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find documents based on multiple text fields.

```
var term = new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i');
.find({ company_name: { $regex: term }});
```

Using the above works great. However, when I try to add an additional field using

```
.find(...).or([{ bio: { $regex: term }}]);
```

it fails to retrieve any records. I need to do this for a few more fields.

The schema has the different text fields indexed, but not together as a single multi-field index. Would this work better and if so, are there any clear examples of this? The documentation that I found was quite sparse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put both fields into an array that's passed to [`or`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or):

```
.find().or([{ company_name: { $regex: term }}, { bio: { $regex: term }}]);
```

Separate single-field indexes are what you want as each `or` term is executed as a separate query.