# Does mongoose have an equivalent $or when using Model.where?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new here. Can someone help me with this:
Does mongoose have an equivalent `$or` when using `Model.where` ?

e.g. 
when using `$and` and `$or` for query

```
var query = {
        $and: [
            {
                startdate: {
                    $lte: activedate
                }
            },
            {
                $or: [{
                    enddate: {
                        $gte: activedate
                    }
                }, {
                    enddate: null
                }]
            }
        ]
    };


    Member.find(query, function (err, members) {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send(err);
        res.status(200).send(members);
    });
```

I want to use `.where` like :

```
Member
        .where('startdate').lte(activedate)
        .where('enddate').gte(activedate)
        .exec(function (err, members) {
            if (err)
                res.status(500).send(err);
            res.status(200).send(members);
        })
```

The purpose of this example is to find members having `startdate` less than `activedate` and `enddate` is null or is greater than `activedate`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose or query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078334/mongoose-or-query)

Comment: I am looking a way to combine .or with .where

Answer (score 0):

It's just '.or' !

Take a look here : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or